# How do I go to a random website? - python

Tags: python, url, random, web, browser

How to generate a random yet valid website link, regardless of languages. Actually, the more diverse the language of the website it generates, the better it is.

I've been doing it by using other people's script on their webpage, **how can i not rely on these random site forwarding script and make my own?**. I've been doing it as such:

```
import webbrowser
from random import choice
random_page_generator = ['http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl',
                         'http://www.uroulette.com/visit']
webbrowser.open(choice(random_page_generator), new=2)
```

Comment: any reason for downvoting?

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this. I could imagine voting to close it, because it's not a coding question, and it may be a little too open-ended, but I think it's answerable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've been doing it by using other people's script on their webpage, how can i not rely on these random site forwarding script and make my own?

There are two ways to do this:

- Create your own [spider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_spider) that amasses a huge collection of websites, and pick from that collection.
- Access some pre-existing collection of websites, and pick from that collection. For example, DMOZ/ODP lets you [download their entire database](http://www.dmoz.org/docs/en/help/getdata.html);* Google used to have a customized random site URL;** etc.

There is no other way around it (short of randomly generating and testing valid strings of arbitrary characters, which would be a ridiculously bad idea).

Building a web spider for yourself can be a fun project. Link-driven scraping libraries like [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org) can do a lot of the grunt work for you, leaving you to write the part you care about.

---

* Note that ODP is a pretty small database compared to something like Google's or Yahoo's, because it's primarily a human-edited collection of significant websites rather than an auto-generated collection of everything anyone has put on the web.

** Google's random site feature was driven by both popularity and your own search history. However, by feeding it an empty search history, you could remove that part of the equation. Anyway, I don't think it exists anymore.

Comment: Probably because it wasn't what they wanted to see, or assumed a condescending tone. +1 for use of `spider` keyword, a great jumping point for research.

Comment: @jwarner112: You're right, `spider` is the key to the whole thing, and maybe that wasn't obvious enough. I added a link to the Wikipedia article, which provides a better jumping-off point than the word itself.

Comment: Though I would bet you could take almost any 2 or 3 random letters together and get a valid .com address from them.

Comment: @microslop: It's only a couple lines of `urllib` code… So, 558 of the 676 URLs of the form `http://XY.com` return a successful result. Of the remainder, 1 returns a DNS error—I really should have made a note of which one—4 return HTTP errors, and a few immediately reject the connection, but the majority just time out.

Comment: @abarnert: Hrm...just about an 85% success rate, not bad.  I just remember a few years back when I registering a domain I found a site that listed available addresses starting from A - ZZZZZ and at first glance it looked like all the 2 and 3 letter names were taken.  But thanks for taking the time to check, it's interesting to know.

Comment: @microslop: Well, 675/676 of the domains are taken (and I'll bet the 676th is currently just in the process of transferring), but 15% of them don't have any server up on port 80 of that domain.

Answer (score 1):

A conceptual explanation, not a code one.

Their scripts are likely very large and comprehensive. If it's a random website *selector*, they have a huge, *huge* list of websites line by line, and the script just picks one. If it's a random URL *generator*, it probably generates a string of letters (e.g. "asljasldjkns"), plugs it between `http://` and `.com`, tries to see if it is a valid URL, and if it is, sends you that URL.

The *easiest* way to design your own might be to ask to have a look at theirs, though I'm not certain of the success you'd have there.

The *best* way as a programmer is simply to decipher the nature of URL language. Practice the building of strings and testing them, or compile a *huge* database of them yourself.

As a hybridization, you might try building two things. One script that, while you're away, searches for/tests URLs and adds them to a database. Another script that randomly selects a line out of this database to send you on your way. The longer you run the first, the better the second becomes.

EDIT: Do Abarnert's thing about spiders, that's much better than my answer.

Comment: "decipher the nature of URL language" is almost meaningless. URLs have a well documented and simple language, but the overwhelmingly vast majority of legal URLs don't locate any resource. It's like trying to generate paragraphs of human text by using random characters and punctuation.

Comment: @abarnert The wording might be vague, it's more about detecting a pattern in *human* speech. For example, a URL generator would likely have more success pairing two common words together (e.g "horse", "ball") than a randomized string of alphanumeric keys (e.g. "h0yze", "c5ü#"). It's a study in speech, simply because humans decide which URLs go places.

Comment: Ah, that's a much more interesting project. There are even research papers on that, although it may be hard to figure out which ones are so out-of-date they're useless. (I remember reading a paper on the statistical likelihood of finding a company online based on company name, brand name, product name, etc., which was really interesting when it was written in the mid 90s, but probably not too helpful today.)

Comment: As someone who is presumably much younger, I've simply grown up in a world where (as a young kid) I was able to ask "so does `www.doghat.com` exist?", and the same principle can easily scale up.

Comment: Well, I too grew up in a world where I could ask that and know the answer instantly too. But that's because it was always "no". :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers suggest building large databases of URL, there is another method which I've used in the past and documented here:

http://41j.com/blog/2011/10/find-a-random-webserver-using-libcurl/

Which is to create a random IP address and then try and grab a site from port 80 of that address. This method is not perfect with modern virtual hosted sites, and of course only fetches the top page but it can be an easy and effective way of getting random sites. The code linked above is C but it should be easily callable from python, or the method could be easily adapted to python.